# Using a URL instead of service name to connect services with docker compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-passport, laravel-sail

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    login:
        build:
            context: ${LOGIN}/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '${LOGIN}:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    companies:
        build:
            context: ${COMPANIES}/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '${COMPANIES}:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    webserver:
        image: 'nginx:alpine'
        volumes:
            - '${NGINX_CONFIG}:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
            - '${NGINX_CONFIG}/certs/:/etc/nginx/ssl'
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - login
            - companies
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
```

The `login` service is used for an OAuth flow (Laravel passport/socialite) by the `companies` service.

The issue I've come across is that redirects break due to certain env variables requiring the `login` service name to send post requests in the internal docker network, but a full url (https://login.test) is required for browser redirects.

The .env variable in question is:

```
LARAVEL_PASSPORT_HOST=login
```

Is there a way to use the full url `https://login.test` in the internal docker network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how to use [network aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#aliases)

For a quick example in your context:

```yaml
    login:
        build:
            context: ${LOGIN}/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '${LOGIN}:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            sail:
              aliases:
                - login.test
        depends_on:
            - mysql
```

Now all machines in the `sail` network will be able to reach the `login` service by using either its service name or the alias `login.test`. Add as many as you wish.